# Work-around for 'No such file or directory' without using absolute paths?

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

I have a Python script inside of `/home/dmbot/`

The contents of `/home/dmbot/` are:

```
root@alpha:~/dmbot# ls -lah
total 40K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.7K Dec 27 18:14 accounts.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  185 Dec 27 18:14 config.py
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Dec 27 18:14 followers
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.8K Dec 27 18:35 script.py
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Dec 27 18:14 tokens
```

When I run my script from the shell while I'm on `/home/dmbot/`, it works fine, but I'm trying to run it from the cron.

I added this line on my crontab:

```
12  19  *   *   *   /usr/bin/python /root/dmbot/script.py
```

When the cron runs, I get this on my root email:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/dmbot/script.py", line 5, in <module>
    execfile('tokens/acc1.py', globals())
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tokens/acc1.py'
```

Since it works fine when I execute it from the shell, why doesn't it work when cron runs it? Will I have to set absolute paths for my entire script?

I coded the script on my local computer and now I uploaded it to a Ubuntu server. I will have to maintain two scripts if I set absolute paths on the entire script, since my computer's folders structure are different from the Ubuntu server.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but is there indeed a file named `acc1.py1` in the `tokens` subdirectory?

Comment: Hi @JustinLardinois, 

Yes there is, since when I run the script from the shell, it works fine.

`root@alpha:~/dmbot/tokens# ls
acc1.py  acc2.py  acc3.py  acc4.py  acc5.py  acc6.py`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the crontab to change directories to where you need it to run from prior to running the script:

```
12  19  *   *   *   cd /home/dmbot ; ./script.py
```

Then on the other computer, just set the crontab to cd to wherever you need it there.

Answer (score 1):

Cron usually runs on root **/**. So your script is probably running there. Now you have two options. Either set absolute path in the script or create another python file, as a configuration file, create the variable there and include it in your script. The variable includes the path of course. This way you only have to maintain one script while the configuration file does not need to be touched on either server.

Answer (score 0):

So, @dtor's solution works, but you'd be safer if instead of requiring people to know they have to run your script from /home/dmbot, you just give your script the ability to figure out where your "tokens" directory is relative to script.py. That way you can run script.py from anywhere, or move the whole project to a directory other than /home/dmbot without breaking anything. You can do this by figuring out where your current file is located and based off that where your tokens dir is located as follows:

```
import sys
import os
abs_script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
execfile(os.path.join(abs_script_dir, 'tokens/acc1.py'), globals())
```

Et voila, now you can run your script from any working directory and be alright, and you're no longer asking for problems later on having to remember the specific place you have to run that script from.